# Why does pasting a certain character change the chronology of the characters in the whole row?

Tags: keyboard, ascii

I've got this funny problem when trying to copy and paste the character٭  It doesn't let me get my cursor behind it and swapps the whole line of characters (see gif). Also the cursor has a funny double cursor, when I highlight ٭

I think I activated some strange mode here accidently with some keys. Anyone know whats going on?

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is a L-R or R-L character set?  Also what is the sequence in hex?

Comment: Hi @cup, thanks for your reply, not quite sure what you mean by L-R or R-L character set. How can I check the hex?

Comment: I don't know where this information is stored or how you can find out.  Anyway left to right the cursor appears on the right of the character to be deleted, right to left, it appears on the left.  The backspace delete and delete key behave differently on a right to left character set (eg when typing in Arabic).

Comment: When I want to use delete key, then its left to right

Comment: I think the hex of that "arabic" star ٭ is 1645; if I use the "normal" star ⋆ (hex 8902) then this funny problem doesn't occur!

Comment: @cup thanks for your tipp, I think you were right with the L-R or R-L character set that causes this backwards to front setting! I thought it was some strange hotkey ubuntu setting, that I accidently activated :') Now I'll just stick with the "normal" star ⋆ and all works like normal.